# Format the output data

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm a novice in programming. Faced with such a problem. Are monitoring servers using Zabbix. It has its own API. The challenge is through a script in Python to connect to the monitor server and get information about printers and their counters and put in the file. The output file should have the format:

name printer   \tab   counter printer

Like that:

HP1212                124512

I connect and receive data, but cannot record it in two columns using a '\t'.
My code:

`

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
zapi = ZabbixAPI("http://*****/zabbix")
zapi.login("******", "*******")
item_name='Print_counter'
hosts = zapi.host.get(                               #get printers  name
                groupids=8,
                output=['name'])
items = zapi.item.get(                               #get printers counter
                groupids=8,
                output=['lastvalue'],
                filter={'name':item_name})`
```

I understand that the problem is likely trivial, but how to solve I don't know.

I edited my question:

If im use:
`for host in hosts:
        a = host['name']
        print a`
 .. I get:

```
tpr001
tpr002
...
tpr020
```

it my printers.

If i use:
`for item in items:
        b = host['value']
        print b`

I get:

```
12456
34645
...
56468
```

It counters off my printers.

I want to group the output of my query like this:

```
tpr001  12456
tpr002  34645
...     ...
tpr020  56468
```

Comment: And if i use for output: for host in hosts:
        for item in items:
                print host['name'],'\t',item['lastvalue'] . It gives me a repeat of the printer names in a column and mixed data

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this :

```
for host in hosts:
    a=host['name']
    for item in items:
        b=item['lastvalue']
        print a,'\t',b`
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly is given by your zapi.host.get and zapi.item.get, but your loops dont work, as you expect.
In your first loop a gets a new value in each cycle so you find the last value in it, if the loop ends. And because of your print command after the loop you see exact that value.

Maybe you should put second loop into the first like

```
for host in hosts:
    a=host['name']
    for item in items:
        b=item['lastvalue']
        print a,'\t',b`
```

But in this case you would combine each row from hosts with each row from items.
Maybe your items.get- command needs the name es filter, something like

```
for host in hosts:
    a=host['name']
    items = zapi.item.get(          #get printers counter
            groupids=8,
            output=['lastvalue'],
            filter={'name':a})
```

Maybe you even do not need to ask for hosts, because all your information are inside items

```
for item in items:
    b=item['lastvalue']
    a=item['name']
    print a,'\t',b
```

Hope, this helps, but I think you should learn about basics in programming, if you want to go further (and it is easier to understand, if you give speaking names instead of a and b, so not only we better understand, what you expect

Comment: I have edited the question, it would be clear that I get the output.

Comment: And you are really sure, that you get names and lastvalues in the same order? There is no way to ask for a special printer name? Try  for item in items: print item to see, what you get

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange to me, that you want to rely on Output order of two different lists. But if so, you could try

```
for i in range(len(Hosts)):
    host = Hosts[i]
    item = Items[i]
    a=host['name']
    b=item['lastvalue']
    print a,'\t',b
```